# Is there any API available to get transaction history from rinkeby test network?

Tags: testrpc, rinkeby, api-design

I want to show this transaction history on my website? Is there any API available for this?
Contract URL: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x104a1fc33d88a3ee8beaf3a61309758174e82b93

[image]

Comment: please follow this link: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/apis

Comment: I am little confused on this https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/apis#transactions 
It require some hash and I need to fetch all transactions. Can you please guide me?

Comment: From where can I get YourApiKeyToken to use in the URL?

Comment: You just read the documentation, its stated that you need to create an account: https://etherscan.io/login?cmd=last . These are the public API for etherscan. In case it doesn't provide what are you looking for there is nothing else that we can do.

Comment: https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xd01a65799aa3dad5f00d57564b5458a17cdb7f35&tag=latest&apikey=DAJXGCCMHISGIW9AISQ8SIWMZBGJ43E9Y1
I got the balance in wei here. But I want to get how much tokens this address has taken from my contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the token balance of any address you can check this 
https://rinkeby.tokenbalance.com/token/0x53576813682009a4D35495e18f039067618B3e27/0x41cb3ec3f126f7705aaf3ba996d96179775b9393

But if you want to get the list of transactions from the address you can use etherscan api
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/apis#transactions

You can use any of the above API acc to your needs and you can use the API key acc to your needs.